# SVN shows insecure at login but secure after login

Tags: svn, ssl-certificate, chromium

I have a SVN server with an SSL certificate installed. This evening I was looking to replace the certificate but came across something I don't understand. The visual-SVN server has local logins for SVN authentication. Upon initially accessing the URL for the repository, the user is prompted with a login box for unsername and password.   This page displays as Insecure but once logged in the page displays as secure.

I guess I'm trying to understand why the SSL only seems to take effect after logging in. Additionally I'm trying to figure out how to make SSL function before the user logs in.

[image: Screenshots before and after login]

The SSL certificate is installed on the server.

> Does SVN require a separate certificate to be installed somewhere
> else?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, this is not a problem of VisualSVN Server, but a problem in Chromium. See https://security.stackexchange.com/q/155414

Chromium had an open ticket for several years [Issue 395050: HTTPS connection details not exposed in HTTP Auth dialog](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=395050) which they decided to close as WontFix.

Comment: I'm using Microsoft Edge and I see the issue too. I have a ! at login, even when I have a valid SSL installed.

Comment: @DaveStuart MS Edge is based on Chromium, so it’s kind of expected that it behaves similar or identically to Chrome and has the same bug.